# Are "the probability of something being seen" and "the probability of someone seeing something" the same?

Tags: distributions, terminology

I'm puzzling over how to treat the distribution of TV advertising spots.

I have a list of spots and the % of the population who saw them.

What I'm trying to get is a Gamma distribution representing the viewing audience and their probability of seeing random spots. Obviously some people watch more TV than others and therefore have a higher chance of seeing a random spot.

I can fit a Gamma distribution to the spots, but I have a nagging feeling that the distribution of spots is not the same as the distribution of viewing probabilities, i.e., the distribution of the probability that a spot was seen is different to the distribution of the probability of someone seeing a spot.

Can someone help me untangle my thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: The distribution of viewing probabilities. What is 'viewing probability'. Does this mean that there are spots which don't get seen at all?

Comment: There are spots that (effectively) don't get seen at all - think 4am on the fishing channel. But more relevant, all spots are only seen by a fraction of the audience. Half-time Superbowl adverts might be seen by 20% of all adults, but one halfway through a repeat of Friends might only be seen by 0.05% of all adults. So that's the distribution of the probability of a random adult seeing a given spot. But what's the probability of an adult seeing one spot, two spots, etc., drawn from that distribution?

Comment: I get it now. You consider a distribution of *the fraction of the public* that sees a spot. A spot that is seen by 0.05% of the public is still a spot that has been seen (at least by some).

Comment: This phrase "the distribution of the probability that a spot was seen" is very confusing to me. It does not convey the idea that you seem to explain in the comment. Also the phrase "the distribution of the probability of someone seeing a spot" is unclear.

Comment: You could explain these sentences by explicitly stating a formula for the concepts in terms of counts. Those probabilities should be some decision of counts. And then the distribution arrises by observing different probabilities (but which parameter is varied to get to a variation is unclear).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Perhaps the problem is that an event of a single person seeing a single spot can be represented by p(i).s(i).
The spot data that I have is created from this set of events by summing up across all people for a spot. But I cannot recreate the original data from this set, which is what I would need to sum across up across all spots for a single person. Therefore I can't get the actual distribution of the probability of people seeing random spots.

Comment: I currently imagine a matrix with rows for viewers $i $ columns for adds $j$, and containing a 1 or 0 for whether or not viewer $i $ saw add $j $. Then the two types of marginal sums relate to your two types of probabilities. And the distribution of them will be different. (imagine an extreme case with zeroes everywhere except in a single column or row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data can be arranged in a matrix as following:

$\begin{array}{cc}
& \text{$n$ viewers} \\
\text{$m$ adds}&\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
& 1 &2 & 3 & ... & n & \text{total} \\ \hline
1& 1 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 &2 \\
2& 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
3& 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 1 & 3\\
\vdots& \\
m& 0 & 0 &0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\text{total} & 2 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 & 5
\end{array}
\end{array}$

The table is ordered as columns for the $n$ viewers and rows for the $m$ adds. A cell $m_{ij}$ contains a $1$ if the viewer $i$ saw add $j$, and it contains a zero otherwise.

The marginal sums show the frequency/counts that an add has been seen or the frequency/counts that a viewer sees an add (I would call it frequency or counts rather than probability).

The distribution of these two types of frequencies will be different as you can see from the example table above. It will not be possible to obtain the one distribution from the other distribution.

Comment: A further question, if I may...
Let's say that the marginal distribution of the adverts is a Beta distribution (In the sense that the proportion of people seeing any advert is strictly between 0 and 1). So if we were to put proportions beside each row, they could be randomly drawn from a Beta distribution.
In that case, could each column in the matrix be effectively Bernoulli trials with the probability given by the Beta-sampled probability of that row? And does that mean that the marginal distribution across the columns would a Beta-Binomial?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to get a binomial and beta distribution for the margins. At the moment I would not know how you get that however, it is certainly possible that you have something different. One model could be to assign probabilities to the margins of the viewers that they are watching, and probabilities on the cells conditional on the fact that the viewer is watching (e.g. each viewer has probability to be watching adds at some time and conditional on that event the adds have probability to be watched be the viewer)......

Comment: .... then the distribution for the adds will be something complicated. It will depend, on the (beta distributed) probability that people watch, and the (undefined distribution) probability that people watch the particular add/chanel conditioned on that they watch. It could be something like [beta-binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) meets [Poisson-binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution)

Comment: The idea of nice distributions is also strange. I would expect mixtures with clusters of people that watch a lot or very little, only the news or only series prime time programs, blockbusters, little watched adds, etc....... Unless there is some system that shuffles everything and makes it strongly related to some distribution that can be derived logically from the principles and mechanisms how people get to see the adds.

Comment: The requirement for trying to work out distributions is because we often need a tractable way of estimating the total reach, the number of people who have seen it once or more, twice or more, etc. We obviously don't have a complete panel of data for this, so we end up estimating based on what we've measured and then some "reasonable" theory to justify our estimates. It's not perfect but it's better than nothing!